# how to init 2 memebers in nested classes in C++

Tags: c++, class, constructor, nested

Hi my win32 question is as follows:
Having 2 classes: class A, and a nested Class B.
Each class has a HWND member.
I want to init both A and B HWND member in constructor BEFORE is called. 
I mean:

```
class A {
    HWND hwnd_main;
    B b;
public:
    A(HWND hwnd) : hwnd_main(hwnd), B(hwnd) {}
};

class B {
    HWND hwnd_main;
public:
    B(HWND hwnd)
    {
        hwnd_main = hwnd;
    }
};
```

The thing that with this scheme constructor of Class "B" is called. 
Isn't a way to fill the constructor of "B" without calling it specifically?
Thx.

Comment: You've made a typo: it should be `b(hwnd)` to call your member `b` constructor. Currently you're just making a new `B` and calling its constructor and then it dies.

Comment: You need to call object's constructor if you want to initialize it and use it later. There's no escape. BTW. there's no nested class in your example?

Comment: There is a nested class. Isn't class B nested into A?

Comment: They mean that if `A` inherited `B`, then you would say `B(hwnd)` to call its constructor; however, you have an object of `B` called `b`, so to initialise it you would call `b(hwnd)`

Comment: This isn't a [nested class](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nested-classes-in-c/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have here is not a nested class but more like an [aggregate](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/103-aggregation/) class.
There is also no inheritance involved here (class `B` is not a direct base of `A`), so you cannot call constructor of `class B` directly in the constructor of `class A` and initialize its variables.

Instead, you have to initialize the variable `b` which is a member of `class A` like this:

```
A(HWND hwnd) : hwnd_main(hwnd), b(hwnd) {}
```